# JVM Startup Flags Not Found

Tags: java, linux, bash

Run the start.sh on Alibaba Cloud Linux 3.2104 64bits

start.sh content:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M
-XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90
-XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs
-Daikars.new.flags=true -jar paper.jar nogui
```

then the console out put:

```
start.sh: line 4: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions: command not found
start.sh: line 5: -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30: command not found
start.sh: line 6: -XX:G1ReservePercent=20: command not found
start.sh: line 7: -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15: command not found
start.sh: line 8: -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5: command not found
start.sh: line 9: -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1: command not found
start.sh: line 10: -Daikars.new.flags=true: command not found
```

java version:

````java
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.2.8.1 (build 17.0.2+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.2.8.1 (build 17.0.2+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)```

I am not a native speaker, sorry for my poor explanation
````

Comment: I tried to delete java and install it again, but nothing happened, it still told me that those command couldn't be found

Comment: These flags copy from PaperMC Docs, which title is Aikar's Flags. here is the link: https://docs.papermc.io/paper/aikars-flags

Comment: If you want to break a command into multiple lines in a shell script, you'll need \ at the end of each line. Otherwise, each line will be interpreted separately.

Comment: Caesar is right. This has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command has multiple lines - in bash shell this must all be on one line or use the line continuation character.  So you have two choices:

All on one line:

```
java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar paper.jar nogui
```

or use a line continuation

```
java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 \
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch \
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M \
-XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 \
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 \
-XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem \
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs \
-Daikars.new.flags=true -jar paper.jar nogui
```

Comment: i think i need to study further about that